# How can I refresh the resolution of a network name in java?

Tags: java, spring, networking, lucene

I am currently writing a Java EE application to search over an index with Lucene.

My application resides in a Tomcat server on a Windows Machine and index data is on another machine.

Sometimes (apparently randomly), the network name becomes unreachable.

This is the exception I get:

```
12:29:39.011 [ajp-8039-5] ERROR o.f.c.d.p.viewmodel.PilotViewModel - The specified network name is no longer available: SimpleFSIndexInput(path="\\INDEXFILEPATH\indexfile.ext")
java.io.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available: SimpleFSIndexInput(path="\\INDEXFILEPATH\indexfile.ext")
at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput.readInternal(SimpleFSDirectory.java:140) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
```

Here is the relevant code. The exception is thrown on the `FSDirectory.open`

```
private void addReaderForRegistry(String indexDirectoryPath, List<IndexReader> readers) throws IOException{

    File indexFolder = new File(indexDirectoryPath);

    if (!(indexFolder.exists() || !(indexFolder.isDirectory()))) {
          throw new IOException(indexFolder.getName() + "is not a valid index location");
    }else{

        // search for subfolders
        List<String> subfolders = FileSystemHelper.listDirectories(indexFolder.getAbsolutePath());

        if(subfolders.isEmpty()){
            Directory fsDirectory = FSDirectory.open(indexFolder);
            IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(fsDirectory);
            readers.add(reader);                
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure that the server is up.

To fix this I have to restart the Tomcat Application Server. Is there something I can do to do some errror recovery?

Note that the FSDirectory is opened at each request, so a simple bean reinitialization does not work.

thanks.

Edit: here is a more complete stacktrace

```
java.io.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available: SimpleFSIndexInput(path="\\hqwprceb1\DRMS-STRUCTURE\indexes_ready\AG\_o48.nrm")
at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput.readInternal(SimpleFSDirectory.java:140) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readBytes(BufferedIndexInput.java:156) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentNorms.bytes(SegmentNorms.java:164) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.norms(SegmentReader.java:575) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery$TermWeight.scorer(TermQuery.java:107) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:298) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$ConstantWeight.scorer(ConstantScoreQuery.java:145) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanQuery.java:298) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:577) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:383) ~[lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:3.6.1 1362471 - thetaphi - 2012-07-17 12:40:12]
```

Comment: While DNS names are exactly for this purpose, because of this issue, with these circumstances (most of the time fixed infrastructure, not changed frequently) I'd rather use the IP address directly, and leave out the DNS from the game...

Comment: Would bonjour/zeroconf be an option? Then refer to "server.local."

Comment: I'll try with ip address. Unfortunately bonjour/zerconf is not an option. thanks anyway.

Comment: The access with IP address did not work unfortunately, in the sense that the issue occurred even if using the ip address

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (loosing sometimes a network drive which later automatically came back; the IndexSearcher didn't recover from this).

My ***workaround*** was to catch the rarely occuring IOException of the IndexSearcher#search call and drop this IndexSearcher instance then (set the reference to it to null). The next request lazyly creates a new IndexSearcher instance (which can fail then, too) in hope of the network drive is available now. Sooner or later the system recovers itself.

I use lucene 3.5, JDK 1.6 and Windows 7.

If someone knows a better solutions -> thanks for pointing to it.

Comment: for debugging purposes I create a new indexreader for every query. It does not work because the exception is thrown during the creation of Reader instances for the IndexSearcher. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at following setting.

http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/11/disable-default-java-dns-caching/

Comment: I'll try this, let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help

Comment: Do you see an IOException? If yes can you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: After some testing I can confirm that this did not help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The link is broken, also the answer should include a short resume regarding the link